# The average number of handshakes between people around a circle.

Tags: combinatorics

> $5$ people are around a circle. At a moment and at the same time each
> person extend their hand to one of their adjacent person. people who
> extended their hand to each other, shaking their hands. In average
> between different possibilities how many hand shakings are done?
>
> $1)\frac32\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad2)1\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad3)\frac23\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad4)\frac54\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad5)\frac12$

First I noticed that for $5$ people we have $2^5=32$ different ways of extending hands (from this we can see third choice $\frac23$ can't be the answer). also maximum number of handshakes is $2$ and it happens in five different cases (at each case there is a person who is not shaking a hand). also minimum number of hand shaking is zero which happens in two cases (all persons extend their hand in a clockwise or counterclockwise directions). so I conclude there are $32-5-2=25$ cases with only one handshake hence the average is $\cfrac{2\times5+25\times1}{32}=\cfrac{35}{32}$. but I don't have this in the choices.

Comment: How familiar are you with the concept of _expectation_?

Comment: @Arthur I am familiar with this concept at elementary level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Establish five random variables $X_i$ for $i = 1, \ldots, 5$ where
$$
X_i = \cases{\frac12 & if person $i$ shook hands with somebody\\
0 & otherwise}
$$
Then note that the quantity we're interested in is $X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4 + X_5$. Or rather, we're after the *expected value* of this sum.

It is known that expectation is linear. Which is to say, we have
$$
E(X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4 + X_5) = E(X_1) + E(X_2) + E(X_3) + E(X_4) + E(X_5)
$$
Each of these five expectations equals $\frac 1{4}$, as there is a $\frac12$ probability that the person they extend their hand to extends back at them.

Which is to say, the final answer is $\frac54$.

As for your approach, there are acutally 10 ways to have two handshakes, as the lone person can reach out in two directions. So you get
$$
\frac{2\times 10 + 20}{32} = \frac{40}{32} = \frac54
$$
Your approach might ultimately be faster, but it is, in my opinion, easier to miss something and get the wrong answer.